# Layout not showing under listview within ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a layout with 1 layout inside of it which is all inside a ScrollView. I am trying to get the whole screen to scroll with the content inside of the listview then the textviews underneath that listview. I get the whole listview to populate and show correctly but the bottom layout with all the textviews do not show up.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bannerReceiptLogo"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/img_logo_receipt_cub" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bannerAddressHeader"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/bannerReceiptLogo"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/storeHeader"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/fullEReceiptListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/bannerAddressHeader"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/fullEReceiptListView"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/totalDivider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorGrey"
                     />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSubTotal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SUBTOTAL"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/totalDivider"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSubTotalFinal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="$13.58"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/totalDivider"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTaxText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TAX"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtSubTotal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTaxTotal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="$0.80"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtSubTotalFinal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCompleteTotal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TOTAL"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTaxText"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCompleteTotalNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="$14.38"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTaxText"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. `ListView` is a widget that is already scrollable. See [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) from Support library.

Comment: So with a NestedScrollView that wont allow the layout to have 2 scrollables? I want the whole view to scroll as 1 unit.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `ListView` height to `wrap_content` the height will have the height to comport all items. That way, the below content will be pushed away.

However Android don't have a great support for nested scrolls, it's considered a bad practice. This way, your `ListView` will not have the native scroll feature, and will need some hack to work as expected.

A better workaround is use the [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html), so you scroll may work (maybe you will need put your `ListView` inside another parent to control the height)

Answer (score 0):

change ListView's layout_height to wrap_content